# Installation of some files in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there a way to somehow install some files that are not .exe,.jar or .msi during installation made in Inno Setup? Precisely, I need to install unfinished project(there is no .jar or .exe) during installation process through Inno Setup. I've used Exec and ShellExec for files that are .exe and .jar , but I don't know if something like this is possible?

Comment: `Exec` and `ShellExec` are not for installing files, but for executing files.  So what do you really want? Install files or execute/open files?

Comment: I want to execute installation of some files when some condition is met. is it possible to be done?

Comment: What do you mean by *"execute installation"*? + Where does your question say anything about any *"condition"*?

Comment: look , im not making some simple installation kit, I have more complex scripting inside inno setup.So lets say that inside function called NextButtonClicked i need to do some if conditioning and if that condition is met to do some installation of files above mentioned,and that's where Exec is appearing as helping tool.Did this help you understand the problem that i occurred here?

Comment: No, we still have some confusion with terms. I do not see what `Exec` has to do with *"installing files"*. You probably mean something else by *"installing"* than I do. What about giving us a real world example? Don't you actually mean *"compiling .java files"* or something like that?

Comment: What im trying to do is when user starts the installation, he/she goes through some steps and when he/she gets to page where i want to ask them if they want to install something ,and if they answer with yes, installation of that other little program is done in the background through Exec.

Comment: *"other little program"* sounds like .exe to me.

Comment: in this moment they are not .exe or .jar or .msi, thats why i'm asking if its possible to copy and somehow install some files that are not yet .exe, but ok, maybe I asked a stupid question, because you can't really install a program if its not .exe or .jar.

Comment: OK, so either make find out what you really need to do and edit your question accordingly. Or delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

Inno does not really care if there is an executable or not, it will happily "install" whatever files you tell it to, all the steps relating to installing an executable are optional.

As a starting point choose the *Create a new script file using the Script Wizard* option  and one of the pages will allow you to specify that *The application does not have a main executable file*.